# How do I append remove icon in my image avatar in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. Trying to build my own project.

I am uploading a profile image in the avatar format, I am trying to append a small remove icon to the image in the bottom corner, which on click would remove the image and set it to default. How do I achieve this in React?

This is my code so far.

```js
const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  ava:{
    paddingTop: '20px',
    paddingBottom: '20px'
  },
  avaContainer: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    paddingTop: '20px',
    paddingBottom: '20px'
  }
})

const ImgTextField = ({label}) =>
  <div style={{
      display: 'inline-block',
      color: Theme.Colors.PRIMARY,
      paddingTop: '8px',
      fontSize: '16px',
      // fontWeight: 'bold',
    }} >
    {label}
  </div>

@observer
class ImageUpload extends React.Component {
  @observable showFields = false
  @observable fields = false
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {file: '',imagePreviewUrl: ''};
  }

  _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // TODO: do something with -> this.state.file
    console.log('handle uploading-', this.state.file);
  }

  _handleRemove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      imagePreviewUrl: null
    });
    this.showfields = false
  }

  _handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.fields = true
  }

  _handleImageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.showfields = true
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({
        file: file,
        imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
      });
    }
    this.fields = false
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.refs.fileUploader.click();
  }

  render() {
    let {imagePreviewUrl} = this.state;
    let $imagePreview = null;
    if (imagePreviewUrl) {
      $imagePreview = (
          <img onClick={(e)=>this._handleChange(e)} src={imagePreviewUrl} />);
    }else {
      $imagePreview =
          <img onClick={(e)=>this._handleChange(e)} src={TestProfileImage}/>
    }

    return (
      <div className ={css(s.container)}>
        {this.fields ?
            <div className={css(s.avaContainer)}>
              <div>
                <img onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} src={UploadSvg} width={70} height={70}/>
                  <input type="file" ref="fileUploader" id="file" style={{display: "none"}}
                    onChange={(e)=>this._handleImageChange(e)}/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ImgTextField label="Upload Photo" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>:
          <div className={css(s.ava)}>
            <div className={classes.avatar}>
                {$imagePreview}
            </div>
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that in React. I'd recommend checking out the docs, and specifically this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: @JordanRunning, maybe this would help.